# MySQLStartupItem.pkg missing from MySQL DMG

Tags: mysql, macos

I downloaded the Mac OS X 10.9 DMG Archive from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I mount and open it, and all I see is the mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64.pkg.

I dont see MySQLStartupItem.pkg anywhere before or after installing the mysql pkg

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  But then I noticed that mysql was actually installed on my preferences pane.  I suspect it is now included in the one installer but they haven't updated the documentation.  I rebooted in between install of mysql and noticing it as already installed, so I don't know whether or not that mattered (I suspect no).  Check your preferences pane under Other and see if it's there...

Comment: Preference pane is installed, but autostart doesn't work. I need MySQLStartupItem.pkg

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.6/en/macosx-installation-prefpane.html).

> Previously, the OS X packages included separate MySQLStartupItem.pkg and MySQL.prefPane files. They have since been merged into the main package file.

So, you just install that package and follow the instruction of this page. What is different is that you need to click mac system preference and search mysql then run mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I had the question too. But if you try the latest installation pkg, say mysql-5.6.23-osx10.9-x86_64.dmg, when you reach "installation type", you click "customize", you will see that the package actually includes: 1)MySQL installation file, 2)MySQL startup items installation file and 3)MySQL.prefPane